# Generating subset of multi-dimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, f#

I'm playing with F# classes by converting one of my existing .NET classes to F#.  The class works with a 2-dimensional array of 8 columns and 10000 rows of 0-1024 integer data

My getPar methods returns a single column of data.  My gatePar takes a lo and hi predicate and returns a 2-tuple of boolean and index.  The tuple tells me if any given index falls within the lo and hi value.

What would be the best way to use the gatePar tuple to return the entire array of true values or values within a limit based upon a single column?

I'm looking to generate a subset of my dataArray with 8 columns and 10000 or less rows.

My code:

```
let mutable lo = int16(300)
let mutable hi = int16(700)

member x.SetLow low = lo <- int16(low)
member x.SetHigh high = hi <- int16(high)

member x.Par =
    x.dataArray.[0..0,0..] 

member x.flatten (dataArray:'a[,]) = dataArray |> Seq.cast<'a>

member x.getRow r (dataArray:_[,]) =
    x.flatten dataArray.[*,r..r] |> Seq.toArray  

member x.getColumn c (dataArray:_[,]) =
    x.flatten dataArray.[*,c..c] |> Seq.toArray

member x.getPar c  =
    x.flatten x.dataArray.[c..c,*] |> Seq.toArray

member x.gatePar c =
    x.flatten x.dataArray.[c..c,*] 
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> x > lo && x < hi, i)
    |> Seq.toArray
```

Calling it from VB.NET:

```vb
inst.SetLow(200)
inst.SetHigh(500)
Dim results = inst.gatePar(2)
```

Comment: you should look into organizing your code as functions in modules rather than classes, it's nicer that way particularly for the kind of utility functions like the ones you posted.

Comment: I thought I understand what you're looking for, but it turns out that I don't. The gatePar function tells you which indices fall within the limit. What do you want to do with that next? Return the original 2D array with rows where nothing is `true` filtered out? Filter out both rows and columns?

Comment: After reviewing Oliver Sturm's F# video on Plural Site, I believe I want to use the map.filter functionality. I want to filter the 2D array by the number of rows while maintaining all columns. I'll post code when I figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for. Made it a module, since it's a better fit, you can go ahead and adapt it for your class.

```
module ArrayFilter =
    /// Converts a jagged array to a multidimensional one.
    /// (if you need to).
    let fromJagged dim1 dim2 (arr: 'a[][]) =
        Array2D.init dim1 dim2 (fun x y -> arr.[x].[y])

    /// Pick only the rows that match the indices.
    let pickRows indices (dataArray:'a[,]) =
        [| for idx in indices do
               yield dataArray.[idx, *]    
            |]                
        |> fromJagged (Array.length indices) (Array2D.length2 dataArray)

    /// the first line is your gatePar, 
    /// the second converts the tuples into indices array.
    let filterIndices lo hi (arr: 'a[]) =
        Array.mapi (fun i x -> x > lo && x < hi, i) arr 
        |> Array.choose (fun (keep, idx) ->
            if keep then Some idx else None)  

    let filterOnColumn c lo hi (dataArray:'a[,]) =
        let indices =
            dataArray.[*, c]
            |> filterIndices lo hi

        pickRows indices dataArray
```

This won't win any awards for efficiency, but seems straightforward and easy to follow.

Comment: I have a 2D array: dataArray(col,row) where col = 8  and row = 10000 containing values between 0-1024
Given a col = x I want to test each row.
Where the value dataArray.[x..x,row] > lo and dataArray.[x..x,row] < hi then return that entire row.
Else skip that row
The resulting 2D array will have 8 cols and n rows: results(8,n)

Comment: In filterOnColumn, the dataArray.[*, c] (or dataArray.[*, c..c]) is multidimensional 'a[,], however filterIndices is expecting a single dimensional array 'a[].  I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the all rows and one column down to a single array.

Comment: For 'a[,] to 'a[] the following appears to be the answer: let toArray (arr:_[,]) = Array.init arr.Length (fun i -> arr.[0, i])